# How to prevent multiple forms having the same input type=hidden values?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have developed a search form that searches a large SQL database using PHP and shows the results to the final user.

There is a GET request going on and then the URL looks like this:

http://localhost/search.php?value1=x&value2=y

Now, aside from showing the search results to the user, I want to show some options that they can
apply to the shown results.

For example, I will have an export to excel button on top of the results, as well as a delete button in order to
delete the results from the database. In my server, those 2 actions will be managed by 2 different files, say
deleteEntries.php and excelExport.php.

So, in my html I will have 2 forms, one pointing at deleteEntries.php and one pointing at excelExport.php.

The problem is that each form needs to have its own inputs type=hidden repeated.

The code

```
<input name="value1" value="x" type="hidden">
<input name="value2" value="y" type="hidden">
```

, which is dynamically generated through PHP, must be repeated for each form (how else can each server-side file know what the
user needs to export or to delete?). The code is dynamically generated because the search criteria and their values will differ
between searches.

Then, if the user chooses to delete the data, the URL will become

http://localhost/deleteEntries.php?value1=x&value2=y

In my specific occassion I have 3 forms and up to 11 values. So this means that I repeat 11 lines of HTML 3 times and I really don't
like that for many reasons.

One obvious solution would be a combobox where I let the user choose the action (e.g. export data, delete data, option 3)
and to manage all the actions with a single form and with a single server-side file by determining the selected action.
But I don't want to do this because it is less user-friendly and less developer-friendly.

Edit: The reason why I don't make a link for Export to excel like

```
<a href="http://localhost/excelExport.php?value1=x&value2=y">Export to excel</a>
```

is because in reality user is given more options that have to be selected from a form.

Comment: why not using POST instead of GET?

Comment: 1. what would POST solve and 2. logically all the actions I want to apply have to do with GETting data from server.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the form action on a submit button as follows:

```
<form method="post">
  <input name="value1" value="x" type="hidden">
  <input name="value2" value="y" type="hidden">
  <button type="submit" formaction="deleteEntries.php">Delete Entries</button>
  <button type="submit" formaction="excelExport.php">Excel Export</button>
</form>
```

Each submitbutton will post to a different php script

This does not work in IE9 and earlier but I do not know if that is a problem

Comment: Please read my question again. I know perfectly well how to do that. I just need multiple forms with the same type="hidden" values and I ask if there is a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the list of hidden inputs to a separate file and include that file in each form template.

Or you could have a list of your parameter names in an array in php. Then generate the hidden inputs from that. That way you can just have a single function call in each form to add in the hidden inputs. You can also loop over the same array in the form handler to read and validate the values received before they are used.

Comment: That's exactly how I've done it. I've moved the PHP code for the dynamically generated inputs and I include it wherever necessary through php `include`. The repetition inside html remains.

Comment: I think html-wise, if the data needs to be sent with the form, you need the fields inside that form. If javascript is an option, you can split those fields out and add some javascript to inject the common data on submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can define onclick function to the buttons rather than sending the form and on the onclick function, you define 2 or more hidden hidden fields to the form you like which means you dont have declare those input on the page load but define it when the onclick function.

```
var y = document.createElement('value1');    
document.form1.appendChild(y);


<form name = "form1" id = "form1" action = "deleteEntries.php" method = "post">
 <button type = "submit" name="submit1" onclick="addinput()">DELETE</button
</form>
```

This the hidden input need not be included in all 3 forms and these fields can be generated dynamically on the particular form button onclick.